# Default 'Find' to Entire Directory

Tags: active-directory

I work in Active Directory alot, and spend time using the 'Find' command to search for users/computers ect.

My issue I am having is, over the past week, the default 'Find In:' has changed. I am trying to get it to be defaulted to 'Entire Directory' but its stuck on one of the other domains.

The highlighted section is the spot that its currently defaulted to.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: @MarcB I understand that, I use this site a lot for programming, but I did see there is a tag for Active Directory, and knowing the knowledge of the users here, I thought it would be worth a shot to ask.

Comment: still doesn't make it a programming question. USING software isn't the same as writing for/with it. try superuser, maybe.